# Aframe *.glb image

Tags: animation, 3d, aframe

I am a newie working with aframe and animated objects, I am doing an exercise in which you can shoot a meteorite in space. I want to replace the 2D image with a 3D image that moves on its axis, I'm using a poly pizza *.glb image, but when I "go live" to see the result, it's a black dot in the middle of the frame. I tried to change the format of the image using *.obj, adding the animation component but it is still the dot in the middle of the frame. Can you help me to see what is wrong or what is missing?

Code:

```
`<a-assets>
    <a-assets-item id="boulder" src="/assets/boulder.glb"></a-assets-item>
</a-assets>
<a-sky src="/assets/sky.jpeg"></a-sky>
<a-entity geometry="primitive: sphere;" radius="2" position="0 0 -20" material="shader: flat; src: #boulder"></a-entity>`
```

And the result:
[gigant dot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHhaU.png)

Answer (score 0):

The '3D image' is not an image - it's a 3D model with its own geometry and its own material. You need to load it with a [loader](https://aframe.io/docs/master/components/gltf-model.html#sidebar) like here:

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.4.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<a-scene>
  <a-assets>
    <a-asset-item id="fox" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/KhronosGroup/glTF-Sample-Models@master/2.0/Fox/glTF-Binary/Fox.glb"/>
    </a-assets>
  <a-entity gltf-model="#fox" scale="0.01 0.01 0.01" position="0 0 -2.25" rotation="0 45 0"> </a-entity>
  <a-box position="-1 0.5 -3" rotation="0 45 0" color="#4CC3D9"></a-box>
  <a-sphere position="0 1.25 -5" radius="1.25" color="#EF2D5E"></a-sphere>
  <a-cylinder position="1 0.75 -3" radius="0.5" height="1.5" color="#FFC65D"></a-cylinder>
  <a-plane position="0 0 -4" rotation="-90 0 0" width="4" height="4" color="#7BC8A4"></a-plane>
</a-scene>
```